# Chrome Beeps on removeAllRanges();

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, beep

Is Chrome beeping during a `removeAllRanges();` to indicate an error in the code, or just that an action has been taken?

My script does not seem to fail...

Comment: Did you install their April Fools extension?

Comment: Google released an April Fool's extension that adds sound effects to various actions.

Comment: Believe it or not, I have no extensions installed when going to:

chrome://extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come after me, the beeping was a consequence of this css property:

```
-khtml-user-select: none;
```

Comment: I'll also add, that line of css made the removeAllRanges break in chrome too.